# How to write Default dictionary values to a file with new line?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following defaultdictionary. I am trying to write values of dictionary to a file. But it is writing in one single line. I want to add new line character after each item. Help ?

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'11163722404385': [('#3\n', '2089', '', '', '', 'Con  verted', '', '', '', 'Mon Apr 22 13:32:00 PDT 2013', 'UNATT')], '1116372240485':
 [('#3\n', '2089', '', '', '', 'Converted', '', '', '', 'Mon Apr 22 13:31:00 PDT
 2013', 'UNATT'), ('#3\n', '2089', '', '', '', 'Converted', '', '', '', 'Mon Apr
 22 13:31:14 PDT 2013', 'UNATT'), ('#3\n', '2089', '', '', '', 'Converted', '',
'', '', 'Mon Apr 22 13:32:00 PDT 2013', 'UNATT')]})

accounts = defaultdict(list)
with open('C:\fileReport.txt', 'a') as csvoutput:  
  writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
  for sid,data1 in accounts.iteritems():
    report = [';'.join(items) for items in data1]
   print report
   finalReport = ['{},{}'.format(sid, ''.join(report))]
   writer.writerow(report)
   writer.writerow('\n')
```

Comment: the indentation as it is is broken. Since this is a likely error, please fix it.

Comment: try using '\r\n\', if you are using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bit of a mess, and you didn't specify what output you were expecting. This does what I think you were trying to do:

**Code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

accounts = defaultdict(list)
accounts['11163722404385'] = [('a', 'list'),('another', 'list')]
accounts['1116372240485'] = [('one', 'more')]

with open(r'C:\temp\out.txt', 'a') as writer:
    for k,v in accounts.iteritems():
        csv = ';'.join([','.join(t) for t in v])
        writer.write("%s,%s\n" % (k, csv))
```

**Output:**

```
11163722404385,a,list;another,list
1116372240485,one,more
```

You may want to rethink your data structures.

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm. When you said I have to rethink the data structure you mean to say defaultdict is not a good option to store values like this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for `pprint`:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(accounts)
{'11163722404385': [('#3\n',
                     '2089',
                     '',
                     '',
                     '',
                     'Converted',
                     '',
                     '',
                     '',
                     'Mon Apr 22 13:32:00 PDT 2013',
                     'UNATT')],
 '1116372240485': [('#3\n',
                    '2089',
                    '',
                    '',
                    <etc.> ]}
```